# Importing a Cython object into a Python file

Tags: python, class, cython

I have code in two files, one of which imports the other.
File1

## parameters.pyx

```
cdef class Parameters:
    cdef int myInt

    def __init__(self, int myInt):
        self.myInt = myInt

    cdef set_myInt(self, int value):
        self.myInt = value

    cdef int get_myInt(self):
        return self.myInt
```

File2

## model.py

```
from parameters import Parameters

def single_run():
    parameters = Parameters(10)
    print(parameters.get_myInt())  # Access it using the get_myInt method

    parameters.set_myInt(100)  # Use the set_myInt method to modify it
    print(parameters.get_myInt())  # Access it again to see the modified value
```

I get the following error:

'parameters.Parameters' object has no attribute 'set_myInt'

Comment: `cdef` functions can't be accessed from python code. Use `cpdef` or `def`. Read the documentation for Cython extension classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call functions/methods defined with `cdef` in other purely Python codes (see [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#c-variable-and-type-definitions)), so you'll have to switch the `cdef` defined methods to either just use `def` or `cpdef`:

```
cdef class Parameters:
    cdef int myInt

    def __init__(self, int myInt):
        self.myInt = myInt

    def set_myInt(self, int value):
        self.myInt = value

    def get_myInt(self):
        return self.myInt
```

**Update**

If you need the `cdef` version of a method, you can have a `def` version that essentially just acts as a wrapper to the `cdef` version, e.g.,

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef int myInt

    def __init__(self, int myInt):
        # stuff

    def my_complex_function(self, value):
        """
        Wrapper to C-version of function.
        """

        return self._my_complex_functon(value)

    cdef int _my_complex_function_c(self, int value):
        # do stuff
        ...
```

Comment: Is there a way I can modify my model.py file so that I can retain the cdef in parameters.pyx; for instance can I change model.py to model.pyx and change some of the class or function definitions therein?

Comment: What I've done in the past is have a simple wrapper function in the `.pyx` file that is defined with `def` that just has the purpose of calling the `cdef` version. I'll add an example to the answer.